# How to remove tomato sauce stains from dishwasher?

Tags: cleaning, kitchen

There are red stains on the white plastic parts on the inside of my dishwasher. I'm guessing they are from tomato / bolognese sauce. Running the dishwasher again does not remove them. What is a good and safe way of cleaning these stains?

Answer (score 3):

Seems like bleach, or a bleach pen, could work. Test it first on a part of the dishwasher that you don't normally see, just to make sure it doesn't cause any discoloration.